# Formatted table based on arrayjob

Tags: conditionals, arrays

I want to setup a `rowcolor` and the cell content of a `tabular` accordingly to the values stored into an array (`arrayjob`). The next MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{arrayjob}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{multido}

\newarray\numbers
\newcounter{cptr}

\newcommand{\updatearray}[1]{
    \stepcounter{cptr}%
    \numbers(\thecptr)=#1%
    Inside updatearray, numbers(\thecptr) = \numbers(\thecptr)\\
}

\begin{document}
    % populating array
    \noindent\updatearray{1}\updatearray{2}\updatearray{3}\updatearray{4}

    % array content
    \noindent Array content\\
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\thecptr}{numbers(\i) = \numbers(\i)\\}

    % array into table
    \noindent This is the table\\
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Numbers}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Output}} \\ \hline
        \let\ListNumbers\empty
        \begingroup
        \let\numbers\relax
        \let\\\relax
        \let\hline\relax
        \multido{\iNumber=1+1}{\thecptr}{
        \xdef\ListNumbers{\ListNumbers
        \numbers(\iNumber) & ifthenelese(numbers(\iNumber)$<3$)(lower+color1)(greater+color2)\\ \hline}}
        \endgroup
        \ListNumbers
    \end{tabular}
    \delarray\numbers
\end{document}
```

gives the output

[image: Output]

The desired output is similar to

[image]

Please note that the `if condition` must depend on the array values.

Comment: Could you please add an example of a “hand-made” table that shows the desired result?

Comment: @egreg with pleasure.

Comment: I hope you're not tied to `arrayjob`; by the way you should use `arrayjobx`, in case.

Comment: The **ith** row in my tabular depends on `\numbers(\i)`. My problem is how to define the `ifthenelse` statement in such way that it adds, dynamically, `rowcolor` at the beginning of the `row` and print "greater" or "lower" accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer you an `expl3` interface:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewArray}{mm}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_aloui_array_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { g_aloui_array_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintArray}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = treshold, #3 = lower color, #4 = higher color
  \aloui_array_print:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_aloui_array_tablebody_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aloui_array_print:nnnn
 {
  % start the table preamble
  \tl_set:Nn \l_aloui_array_tablebody_tl
   {
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Numbers}} & \textbf{Output} \\
    \hline
   }
  % add rows
  \seq_map_inline:cn { g_aloui_array_#1_seq }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { ##1 < #2 }
     {% the item is below the treshold
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aloui_array_tablebody_tl
       {
        \rowcolor{#3} ##1 & lower \\ \hline
       }
     }
     {% the item is above the treshold
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aloui_array_tablebody_tl
       {
        \rowcolor{#4} ##1 & higher \\ \hline
       }
     }
   }
  % finish up the table
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aloui_array_tablebody_tl { \end{tabular} }
  % print the table
  \tl_use:N \l_aloui_array_tablebody_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NewArray{aloui}{1,2,3,4}

\PrintArray{aloui}{3}{red!60}{red!20}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It would be easy to adapt to floating point values.